# How to detect if browser window is "near" the bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using the infinite scrolling for my react app and have this function that detects when I'm exactly at the bottom of the page:

```
const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);

// Fire Upon Reaching the Bottom of the Page
  const handleScroll = () => {
    if (
      window.innerHeight +
        Math.max(
          window.pageYOffset,
          document.documentElement.scrollTop,
          document.body.scrollTop
        ) !==
      document.documentElement.offsetHeight
    )
      return;

    setIsFetching(true);
  };

  // Debounce the Scroll Event Function and Cancel it When Called
  const debounceHandleScroll = debounce(handleScroll, 100);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", debounceHandleScroll);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", debounceHandleScroll);
  }, [debounceHandleScroll]);

  debounceHandleScroll.cancel();
```

The problem lies when I load my page in my phone and it seems that because of the tab or bar of the mobile browser, it's not detecting the bottom of the page and so the content doesn't load.

**Is there any way I can detect that the user is near the bottom and fire that function only then?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to changed the scroll function into this and now it's working.

```
  const handleScroll = () => {
    if (
      window.innerHeight +
        Math.max(
          window.pageYOffset,
          document.documentElement.scrollTop,
          document.body.scrollTop
        ) >
      document.documentElement.offsetHeight - 100
    ) {
      setIsFetching(true);
    } else {
      return;
    }
  };
```

The number that's being reduced from `document.documentElement.offsetHeight` determines the amount remaining from the bottom of the page. 100 seems enough for me since I tested it on my phone and it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think an IntersectionObserver could be what you're looking for.
You can check this tutorial for for basic information: https://dev.to/producthackers/intersection-observer-using-react-49ko

You could also turn this into a custom hook which takes a ref (in your case, a n element at the bottom of you page):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useIsVisible = ref => {
  const [isIntersecting, setIntersecting] = useState(false);

  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) =>
    setIntersecting(entry.isIntersecting),
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    observer.observe(ref.current);

    return () => {
      observer.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  return isIntersecting;
};

export default useIsVisible;
```

Maybe also the following package might help you, it makes implementing infinity scroll quite easy:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroll-component

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there any way to do it with plain JS? I really don't have the time to change everything currently

Comment: Intersection Observer is not React's own feature. It's browser API so you can use IO in vanilla JS